# Stop a mailbox syncing between 9am and 5pm

Tags: notifications, email

I have my work emails set up on my LG G3, but when I'm at work I don't want to be getting notifications on it whilst getting them on my laptop as well.

Is there a way to stop a mailbox from syncing for a particular period? E.g., from 9am to 5pm?
I still want my other accounts to sync and notify me though, like my personal/other work email addresses.

Is there an app that can handle this? I've just come from an iPhone 4s (yesterday) so I'm still getting my head around the Android ecosystem.

Answer (score 2):

That sounds like a perfect job for [tasker](/questions/tagged/tasker) (see the [tasker tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/tasker/info) for some background). Example profile in "Pseudo-Code":

- **Condition:** Time, start: 9am, end: 5pm
- **Task:** Sync off
- **Exit-Task:** Sync On

**Notes:**

- "Exit-Task" is optional. If not defined, *Tasker* restores the state from before the Task started.
- "Sync Off" applies to more than just mail (includes e.g. contacts, calendars, etc.). If you want to only pause mail sync, you need a mail app with *Tasker* support, e.g. [K-9 Mail](http://www.appbrain.com/app/k-9-mail/com.fsck.k9), maybe with some additional plugin. I know that's possible with *K-9*, and it's more than likely there are some other supported [Email Apps](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists.php?topic=cat;id=107). If using such a client, replace the "Sync off" / "Sync on" with the corresponding plugin action.